# Setting string equal to match found by Rails regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string

I'm trying to pull the user_id from a foursquare URL, like this one:

```
 https://foursquare.com/user/99999999
```

The following regex pulls exactly what I need (a series of numbers that terminate with the end of the line):

```
\d+$
```

However, I'm not sure how to set a string equal to the matched characters. I'm aware of sub and gsub, but those methods substitute a matched string for something else.

I'm looking for a way to specifically pull the section of a string that matches my regex (if it exists)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I like to use the return of match():

Anything wrapped in a capture () in the regex, gets assigned to the match result array

```
"https://foursquare.com/user/99999999".match(/(\d+)\z/)[1] #=> "99999999"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>> "https://foursquare.com/user/99999999"[/(\d+)\z/, 1]
=> "99999999"

>> "https://foursquare.com/user/99999999" =~ /(\d+)\z/
=> 28
>> $1
=> "99999999"

>> "https://foursquare.com/user/99999999".split('/').last
=> "99999999"
```

There are many ways. I personally like `String#[]` though

Comment: Interesting to see there are multiple ways of doing this. Out of curiousity, could you explain the syntax of the second one?

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-7E

Captures are stored in $1 to $9

Comment: Also just a FYI, using `String#match` is slower than anything I have shown you in my answer